# Sql query parameterization in javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I've been trying to implement a parameterized sql query in javascript. It seems to work when only one parameter is passed with the query.

```
yield db.execute("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name = @0", [foo] );
```

But the problem is when I try to implement two parameters in the same query.

```
yield db.execute("DELETE FROM table1 where table1_id = @0 AND name = @1", 123, [foo]);
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass both query arguments **in** the array:

```
yield db.execute("DELETE FROM table1 where table1_id = @0 AND name = @1", [123, foo]);
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

You were passing the `execute` function the query, `123`, and `[foo]` rather than passing it the query and `[123, foo]`.